Values over bars in barplot not centered
I have the following code, which produces a plot, that plots two dictionaries next to each other, where the y-axis are the days and the y-axis the relative costs. Since the plot is pretty bloated, i want to add the values over each bar, ideally centered. Thus, I added the option ha='center' to my code, but somehow it produces a plot, where the rotated values are not truly centered above the bar. I want the middle of the rotated number centered over the bar. How can i achieve that?
This is my code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

def plot_relative_undercover_dual(ls1, ls2, demand_dict, days, shifts):
    list1, list2 = [], []

    for day in range(1, days + 1):
        daily_sum1 = sum(ls1.get((day, shift), 0) for shift in range(1, shifts + 1))
        daily_sum2 = sum(ls2.get((day, shift), 0) for shift in range(1, shifts + 1))
        daily_demand_sum = sum(demand_dict.get((day, shift), 0) for shift in range(1, shifts + 1))

        if daily_demand_sum > 0:
            relative1 = daily_sum1 / daily_demand_sum
            relative2 = daily_sum2 / daily_demand_sum
        else:
            relative1 = relative2 = 0

        list1.append(relative1)
        list2.append(relative2)

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

    x = np.arange(1, days + 1)
    width = 0.35

    colors = plt.cm.magma([0.8, 0.2])

    bars1 = plt.bar(x - width / 2, list1, width, color=colors[0], alpha=0.7, label='Option 1')
    bars2 = plt.bar(x + width / 2, list2, width, color=colors[1], alpha=0.7, label='Option 2')

    plt.xlabel('Days', fontsize=14.5, labelpad=15)
    plt.ylabel('Relative Costs', fontsize=14.5, labelpad=15)

    plt.grid(axis='y', linestyle='--', alpha=0.7)
    plt.xticks(x)

    def add_value_labels(bars):
        for bar in bars:
            height = bar.get_height()
            plt.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2., height + 0.01,
                     f'{height:.2%}',
                     ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90, fontsize=10, color='black')

    add_value_labels(bars1)
    add_value_labels(bars2)

    # Find the maximum height of all bars
    max_height = max(max(bar.get_height() for bar in bars1), max(bar.get_height() for bar in bars2))

    # Add a margin above the highest bar for the labels and legend
    legend_margin = 0.15 * max_height
    plt.ylim(top=max_height + legend_margin)

    # Erstelle die Legende mit dünnerem Rahmen
    legend = plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.02, 0.98), ncol=1, frameon=True, edgecolor='black', facecolor='white', framealpha=1, fontsize=14.5)  # Set font size to match axis labels
    legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.5)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def generate_random_data(days, shifts, min_value, max_value):
    return {(day, shift): round(random.uniform(min_value, max_value), 2) for day in range(1, days + 1) for shift in range(1, shifts + 1)}

demand_dict, u1, u2 = generate_random_data(28, 3, 0, 105), generate_random_data(28, 3, 0, 100), generate_random_data(28, 3, 0, 100)

plot_relative_undercover_dual(u1, u2, demand_dict, 28, 3)

Here you can see the output and the problem more clearly:


Try some other fontsize and see if it still shows the same problem.

@Cincinnatus Yes it does still persist.

The values are not centered, but the text box is, as the text box extends below (here to the left due to the rotation) to account for lower case letters that extend below the baseline (i.e. g, j, p, q, y). You can visualize the text box by adding the following to your plt.text call:
plt.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2., height + 0.01, f'{height:.2%}',
         ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90, fontsize=10, color='black',
         bbox=dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='red', pad=0.))

This answer outlines a workaround to offset the text such that it appears centered when there are no letters extending below the baseline.
